# Swap grows slowly with 80% available memory

Tags: rsync, raspberry-pi, memory, raspbian, swap

This has few views - so let me try with a tl;dr

> Is my claim that there should be plenty of free memory correct? Or am I misinterpreting [Meaning of the buffers/cache line in the output of free](https://serverfault.com/a/85481/228063)? Can I reasonably claim that the system is using swap when it should not?

I *think* my system is swapping itself to death. There is however plenty of free memory. Can someone help me understand this? Or help me prove that this is not the issue?

I have spent quite some time debugging this but have awfully little to show for it. Already established ssh sessions remain running but cannot create any new. The system responds to ICMP ECHO (ping).

It smells like a resource issue but my daily driver is FreeBSD so I am not sure I am looking in the right places. The first couple of times I saw this was with a long running `rsync` job (TBs of data).

The system has 4 Gb of memory. Throughout I am told I have around 3400 MiB avail Mem. I see that buff/cache fills up. With a lot of file activity this is normal. I do however expect that the system frees some of the filesystem cache rather than going to swap!

Swappiness is left at the default:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
60
```

From experience I prefer to have swap space. I have so far choosen to keep the swap file at 100 MB. This is because I think something is going on. Just throwing 4 or 8 GB after a swap file would probably make this go away. But I would like to understand what is happening as I would not expect this system to swap.

And we do not overcommit:

```
$ sysctl vm.overcommit_memory
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
```

After quite some debugging I ended with a pretty minimal set of processes running. Then I started a rsync copy from a cifs mount to a local disk with 3,2 TB in 16396 files. This is what I saw:

```
top - 19:46:53 up 17 min,  3 users,  load average: 0,70, 0,24, 0,10
Tasks: 126 total,   2 running, 124 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 25,2 us,  4,1 sy,  0,0 ni, 68,3 id,  0,7 wa,  0,0 hi,  1,7 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   3727,6 total,   2259,5 free,    180,1 used,   1288,0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100,0 total,    100,0 free,      0,0 used.   3405,7 avail Mem

top - 20:04:21 up 34 min,  3 users,  load average: 1,90, 1,68, 1,18
Tasks: 125 total,   2 running, 123 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 27,9 us,  3,2 sy,  0,0 ni, 64,0 id,  3,6 wa,  0,0 hi,  1,3 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   3727,6 total,    176,0 free,    180,6 used,   3371,0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100,0 total,     94,7 free,      5,3 used.   3410,9 avail Mem

top - 08:51:13 up 13:21,  3 users,  load average: 2,46, 1,92, 1,69
Tasks: 126 total,   2 running, 124 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 25,0 us,  4,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 68,8 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  1,6 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   3727,6 total,    282,4 free,    147,9 used,   3297,3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100,0 total,     49,0 free,     51,0 used.   3433,4 avail Mem

[08:55:27] pi@pie:~ $ vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 3  0  73168 271992  12888 3402752    0    1     6   184  213  106 26  5 66  3  0

 top - 08:56:12 up 13:26,  3 users,  load average: 1,97, 2,06, 1,83
Tasks: 124 total,   2 running, 122 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 25,7 us,  3,9 sy,  0,0 ni, 59,6 id,  9,5 wa,  0,0 hi,  1,3 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   3727,6 total,    262,4 free,    125,5 used,   3339,7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100,0 total,     26,2 free,     73,8 used.   3454,9 avail Mem
```

I saw that swap usage kept slowly rising and I was sure this would kill the system. But no. The highest value I saw was 75,3 MB. Then it dropped to around 50 and started climbing again. As a small sidenote I should say that I only saw a speed 10MB/s. This is about half of what is expected from this [benchmark](https://www.pidramble.com/wiki/benchmarks/networking). For now I attribute this copying from a cifs mount but have not investigated this further.

```
[09:05:03] pi@pie:~ $ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3817056 kB
MemFree:          273304 kB
MemAvailable:    3542092 kB
Buffers:           10068 kB
Cached:          3319120 kB
SwapCached:          480 kB
Active:            48600 kB
Inactive:        3317168 kB
Active(anon):      18020 kB
Inactive(anon):    20600 kB
Active(file):      30580 kB
Inactive(file):  3296568 kB
Unevictable:          16 kB
Mlocked:              16 kB
HighTotal:       3080192 kB
HighFree:          17628 kB
LowTotal:         736864 kB
LowFree:          255676 kB
SwapTotal:        102396 kB
SwapFree:          24572 kB
Dirty:             46080 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         36220 kB
Mapped:            15364 kB
Shmem:              2020 kB
Slab:             120440 kB
SReclaimable:      89344 kB
SUnreclaim:        31096 kB
KernelStack:        1072 kB
PageTables:         1564 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2010924 kB
Committed_AS:     235180 kB
VmallocTotal:     245760 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:              608 kB
CmaTotal:         262144 kB
CmaFree:          222808 kB

top - 09:18:32 up 13:48,  3 users,  load average: 1,90, 1,54, 1,54
Tasks: 125 total,   2 running, 123 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 26,0 us,  3,8 sy,  0,0 ni, 67,4 id,  1,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  1,8 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   3727,6 total,    261,0 free,    122,3 used,   3344,3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100,0 total,     24,7 free,     75,3 used.   3458,9 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1004 pi        20   0   22060   4812   1560 R 100,0   0,1 806:11.21 rsync
 1010 pi        20   0   27716   2412    936 S  12,3   0,1 109:06.03 rsync
  829 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   8,6   0,0  66:54.19 cifsd
   47 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1,3   0,0  13:29.04 kswapd0
   79 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1,0   0,0   6:17.58 usb-storage
 5634 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   1,0   0,0   0:05.07 kworker/u8:3-flush-8:16
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,7   0,0   7:14.45 ksoftirqd/0

top - 09:18:32 up 13:48,  3 users,  load average: 1,90, 1,54, 1,54
Tasks: 125 total,   2 running, 123 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 26,0 us,  3,8 sy,  0,0 ni, 67,4 id,  1,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  1,8 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   3727,6 total,    261,0 free,    122,3 used,   3344,3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100,0 total,     24,7 free,     75,3 used.   3458,9 avail Mem

top - 11:47:09 up 16:17,  4 users,  load average: 1,57, 1,61, 1,75
Tasks: 128 total,   2 running, 126 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 28,6 us,  5,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 62,9 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  2,9 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   3727,6 total,    280,9 free,    155,2 used,   3291,5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100,0 total,     46,9 free,     53,1 used.   3426,3 avail Mem

top - 12:32:23 up 17:02,  5 users,  load average: 1,36, 1,39, 1,40
Tasks: 133 total,   2 running, 131 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 26,5 us,  5,9 sy,  0,0 ni, 66,2 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  1,5 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   3727,6 total,    274,7 free,    153,2 used,   3299,7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100,0 total,     46,1 free,     53,9 used.   3428,2 avail Mem

top - 10:47:38 up 1 day, 15:17,  3 users,  load average: 1,57, 1,69, 1,88
Tasks: 125 total,   2 running, 123 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 25,8 us, 12,1 sy,  0,0 ni, 60,6 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  1,5 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   3727,6 total,     74,1 free,    155,1 used,   3498,4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100,0 total,     47,5 free,     52,5 used.   3427,6 avail Mem
```

So 16396 files with 3,2 TB made me conclude that it was not a disk issue nor (directly) a memory leak in rsync.

Now I then suspect that it is a system problem when running rsync. My general assumption is that the filecache usage can grow if there is free memory. But I also expect this memory to be released before swapping. There is probably a low watermark for this but we should be nowhere near that.

As nothing happened I then started a new rsync with a 530 GB/3147 files subset of the previous copy. This time I was lucky enough to trigger the same symptoms when logged in. I wanted to look closer into what was swapping and installed `smem`. My expectation is that cache was not released and I then cause excessive swapping. This is what it looked like:

```
[21:15:21] pi@pie:~ $ sudo apt-get install smem
....snip....
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.13.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
[21:15:49] pi@pie:~ $ smem -t
  PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS
  496 pi       /lib/systemd/systemd --user      752      244      394     1524
25950 pi       tmux a                             0      404      815     2832
22475 pi       rsync --info=progress2 --ou        0     1000     1250     2676
  992 pi       -bash                              0      924     1277     2952
25939 pi       -bash                             12      916     1394     3620
25915 pi       -bash                              0      932     1402     3672
22477 pi       rsync --info=progress2 --ou        0     1820     2000     2912
  991 pi       tmux new -s filecopy               0     1776     2110     3364
26241 pi       /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/sm        0     5480     5661     7352
22474 pi       rsync --info=progress2 --ou        0    21972    22253    23988
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   10 1                                         764    35468    38556    54892
[21:15:55] pi@pie:~ $ top
-bash: /usr/bin/top: Input/output error
Bus error
[19:18:41] pi@pie:~ $ top
-bash: /usr/bin/top: Input/output error
Bus error
[19:18:51] pi@pie:~ $ htop
-bash: htop: command not found
Bus error
[19:19:01] pi@pie:~ $ smem -t
-bash: /usr/bin/smem: Input/output error
Bus error
[19:19:15] pi@pie:~ $ exit
logout
-bash: /home/pi/.bash_logout: Input/output error
-bash: /etc/bash.bash_logout: Input/output error
```

Notice how the time jumps back from 21 to 19. I am in GMT+1 so this could be forgetting the TZ and just giving me UTC. It seems to be `systemd` which does the swapping and not rsync?

At the same time I lost connection to `logitechmediaserver` running on the box. I had another ssh session running with tmux to show the progress of rsync. rsync was running happily. I was not able to create a new window in tmux. When I detached from the session I lost the ssh connection. I could ping the box but not get in contact with any service.

If the system is starved I am not sure it would be able to write anything useful to a log. At least I could not find anything in `/var/log/messages` nor `/var/log/kern.log`

Only a slightly interesting entry in `/var/log/syslog`

```
May 12 21:10:01 pie CRON[25959]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/flock -w 0 /tmp/syncmusic.lock /usr/bin/nice -n 10 /home/pi/syncmusic.sh > /tmp/syncmusic.log)
May 12 21:15:01 pie CRON[25985]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/flock -w 0 /tmp/syncmusic.lock /usr/bin/nice -n 10 /home/pi/syncmusic.sh > /tmp/syncmusic.log)
May 12 21:15:49 pie dbus-daemon[317]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.43' (uid=0 pid=26225 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus call --system May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd-modules-load[106]: Inserted module 'i2c_dev'
May 12 20:53:52 pie fake-hwclock[110]: Tue May 12 18:17:01 UTC 2020
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd-fsck[129]: e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
May 12 20:53:52 pie fake-hwclock[110]: Tue May 12 18:17:01 UTC 2020
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd-fsck[129]: e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started Set the console keyboard layout.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Starting Helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown...
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started Helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd-fsck[129]: rootfs: clean, 123935/28436352 files, 2873219/117146326 blocks
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started File System Check on Root Device.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started Create System Users.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 156 (plymouthd).
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
May 12 20:53:52 pie kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
May 12 20:53:52 pie systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
May 12 20:53:52 pie kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.19.97-v7l+ (dom@buildbot) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611)) #1294 SMP Thu Jan 30 13:21:14 GMT 2020
```

The timestamp 21:15:49 fits with the installation of `smem` but I am not sure what to make of "Inserted module". This is how the line actually looks - not a copy error. There is no LF.

At least I now have an idea on how to reproduce. I am currently waiting for my swap to heat up again.

This is seen on a Pi 4 with an up-to-date Raspbian:

```
 $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
[23:38:00] pi@pie:/mnt/piedisk $ uname -a
Linux pie 4.19.97-v7l+ #1294 SMP Thu Jan 30 13:21:14 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Is my claim that there should be plenty of free memory correct? Or am I misinterpreting [Meaning of the buffers/cache line in the output of free](https://serverfault.com/a/85481/228063)? Can I reasonably claim that the system is using swap when it should not?

**Update 1:** I need to educate myself `slabtop` and what is going on there. I have still seen no trace of the OOM killer in any crash. I intended to run some more tests to be able to reproduce properly as it takes too long even with a small swap of 100M. I intend to reduce the swap to 0, 1M and 10M to see if I can provoke the error.

Comment: reducing swappiness while leaving the swap file its current size seems to be a reasonable solution

Comment: As I read [swappiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Swappiness) it does not seem reasonable to me. If I lower it it will reduce the relative weight given to swap (even to the point of disabling it). My point is that it should drop pages from the page cache at least at that time. What (I think) I see is the OOM run amok when there is plenty of memory. Swappiness should not change that - only maybe the "when". In my use case it is even suggested to [set swappiness higher](https://web.archive.org/web/20130524085654/http://kerneltrap.org/node/3000). Or am I missing something?

Comment: The OOM killer would leave traces in the system logs. I’m intrigued by the I/O and bus errors; didn’t they leave any trace in the kernel logs?

Comment: I checked once again to make sure. kern.log only shows the latest boot with nothing before the last boot 3 days earlier in kern.log.1. messages again have the latest boot and then the HUP of rsyslogd at midnight the previous days. I have added the following lines in syslog which I assumed was boot related. Notice the missing LF.  Unfortunately there is no screen attached to the system. Anything else than OOM which can likely block new ssh connection but leave existing running?

Comment: have you looked at `slaptop`?  maybe inode/dentry' caching not cleared, can you try setting `vm.vfs_cache_pressure` to a higher value?

Comment: No. From idle system starting rsync will use up cache. After 2 GB copied buff/cache ~= avail Mem and swap starts growing. I will install `slaptop` and have a look. `vm.vfs_cache_pressure` currently at 100

Comment: Took me 5 minutes to figure out it was `slabtop` - learned something new :-) Currently `Objects (97,6%)`, `Slabs (100,0%)`, `Caches (79,3%)`, `Size (94,6%)`.

Comment: Top objects `buffer_head` and `radix_tree_node` shows constant activity. `skbuff_head_cache` shows a little activity. `dentry` and `inode_cache` seems fixed. Will monitor a little longer for baseline.